# Proper cleanup of CComSafeArray<VARIANT>

Tags: com, variant, safearray, ole-automation

Given:

```
{
    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> sa;
    CComVariant ccv(L"test");
    sa.Add(ccv, TRUE);
}
```

I was hoping the dtor of CComSafeArray would call ::VariantClear on each contained member and the documentation seems to indicate that:

In certain cases, it may be preferable to clear a variant in code without calling VariantClear. 
For example, you can change the type of a VT_I4 variant to another type without calling this 
function. **Safearrays of BSTR will have SysFreeString called on each element** not VariantClear. 
However, you must call VariantClear if a VT_type is received but cannot be handled. **Safearrays 
of variant will also have VariantClear called on each member**.

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165(v=vs.85).aspx)

But I see no such thing happening in the code in atlsafe.h.

Am I just looking in the wrong place or is this just supposed to happen as a side-effect of ::SafeArrayDestroy() -- which is the only thing happening via the CComSafeArray dtor.

Comment: Hard to guess where you get this stuff.  There is a template method specialization for `CComSafeArray<BSTR>::SetAt()` but that's where the micro-optimizations end.  Sure you are looking in the wrong place, you can't see the source code for SafeArrayDestroy or VariantClear unless you work for Microsoft.

Comment: SafeArrayDestroy is documented like this: "Safe arrays of variant will have the VariantClear function called on each member", so you should be fine

Comment: It does happen as a side effect of `SafeArrayDestroy`. It does proper clean-up on each element, suitable for the element type.

Comment: If one of you gentlemen convert this to an answer, I will mark it as Accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately `VariantClear` will get called on the contents of the CComSafeArray object, albeit after progressing through multiple layers.  `CComSafeArray::~CComSafeArray()` calls `CComSafeArray::Destroy()` which is ultimately a wrapper of `SafeArrayDestroy()`:

```
HRESULT Destroy()
{
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
    if (m_psa != NULL)
    {
        hRes = Unlock();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
            hRes = SafeArrayDestroy(m_psa);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
                m_psa = NULL;
        }
    }
    return hRes;
}
```

[`SafeArrayDestroy()` is documented as calling `VariantClear` on its contents if it contains VARIANTs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221702(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Safe arrays of variant will have the VariantClear function called on
>   each member and safe arrays of BSTR will have the SysFreeString
>   function called on each element.